# Retain View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, retain, ibaction, dealloc

I am using MJDetailViewController as a popup controller which manages In-App purchases on my app.

As this view controller can be called multiple times I cannot release it in the usual way of

```
- (IBAction)8Button {
MJDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MJDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopTop];
[detailViewController release];
}
```

As if the user the clicks on it again it causes the app to crash.

As it is not being released it is causing a memory leak that i need to fix. I assume I need to retain the detailViewController and release it at the dealloc stage however I do not know how to do this.

The code to load the detailViewController is as followed:

```
- (IBAction)8Button {
MJDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[MJDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MJDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentPopupViewController:detailViewController animationType:MJPopupViewAnimationSlideTopTop];
}
```

Any help would be very much welcome...

Comment: As its only reference is stored in a local variable, how can it "be called multiple times"?

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the detail view controller you shouldn't be releasing it, you should be doing:

```
[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Thats what it is set on at the moment as this was the default anyway, However when i Analysis it on Xcode it comes up with "Potential leak of an object stored into 'detailViewController'

Comment: How can the user 'click on it again'? After it has been dismissed?

Comment: The popupviewcontroller sits on top of the main view controller. When the background is tap it closes the popupviewcontroller so the button to open it back up again is still on the main view controller so the user could select it again.

Comment: But that would create a new one to display